# Playing music files for a specified time even if power button is pressed

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media

I have written an Android application that plays music files for a specified time (e.g. for 6 minutes). The annoying problem is that, if user presses power button and/or display turns off, playing music is continued, and does not stop after 6 minutes. Do I need to use services?

Answer (score 1):

You don't explain how your code is working at the moment but it sounds like the device goes to sleep so your app is not able to stop the music.  The best way to get around this is probably to create an [alarm](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) that will trigger at the time you want the music to stop.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Dear Dan, currently my application uses AndEngine and handles playing musics with "void update(float elapsedTime)" function. But as you told, when the device goes to sleep, this update function does not work. Using Alarm, how I can access to media player instance that is playing music?